# reject other domain point to mine

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I find one domain redirect to my website I don't know why? and how to reject that?
I use apache,php(slim framework) and I edit .htaccess file , I add last two line
I'm not sure did I doing correct? any missing mistake?
and how to also accept `mydomain.com` without `www` ?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can swap the rule and make `www` optional:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks so much!! it works! do you know why the unknown domain point to mine?  and is there anything more I should do?

Comment: unknown domain pointing to you seems weird, you should talk to your hosting admins for this problem as I suspect some misconfiguration also.

Comment: I saw one weird url in my google analytics , such like `mydomain/mysearch/q? cache= ...  ` insert the `cache=`